# Is an index signature the correct solution to my React props TypeScript interface problem?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my component.

```
interface FormGroupProps {
  label: string;
  [otherProps: string]: any; 
}

const FormGroup = ({ label, ...otherProps }: FormGroupProps) => (
  <div>
    <label>
      {label}
      <input {...otherProps} />
    </label>
  </div>
);
```

As you can see, I am using an index signature in my props interface to allow the instances of my component to pass any attributes to my input element.

Is this the correct way to solve this problem or a hack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a solution. The problem with it is that now you basically loose all type checking on the props of your component, since any key is allowed with any type.

A better solution would be to extract the props of `input` using `React.ComponentProps`. You can then use an intersection type to add your extra property. Like this you will get your new field and get all the props of from `input` and all will be type checked:

```
type FormGroupProps = {
  label: string;
} & React.ComponentProps<'input'>

const FormGroup = ({ label, ...otherProps }: FormGroupProps) => (
  <div>
    <label>
      {label}
      <input {...otherProps} />
    </label>
  </div>
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAMWhAHEcBXMABRzAGc4BeOAG9ScOABsUAIyTiAXHB4wowAHYBzANykAvnABkiYjAB0AYVyRVSVTC4ReAHnxqwrGPgB85NBFVL6RhYIdgE4AAohCWlZABo4E0SIGAALJCh7XjgdBQYoZjZObh4ASgFPCNE4RwATYAA3bzExR0kZcSbmsSE22R0qrsdXd2FEk2S0jOK9AHpOlpnejqrHGbrG0hLNIA)

Comment: Thank you so much dude! I will accept your answer ASAP.

Comment: Me again! For a styled component would I use `& React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'input'>;`?

Comment: @hugojavadi Not sure, I don't use styled components, I would need your exact code to form an opinion.